# Custom routing in .NET Core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

Can you help me to create custom routing in .NET Core 3?

If the url looks like this:

```
 abc.com/tiger-animal
```

then I want to execute the `Index` method on the `AnimalController` and pass `tiger` as query string or `Id` parameter.

When url looks like this: `abc.com/aboutus`, the routing should execute the `Index?  method on the`aboutus` controller as in the default.

Which means I want to execute `AnimalController` if the url contains last string as `-animal` .

I have tried

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("blog", "{*id}-animal",
                         defaults: new { controller = "animal", action = "index" });
                routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Side note: you don't **execute a controller** - you can execute a **method** (like the `Index` method) on a controller, but you cannot "execute" the "whole" controller as such .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the asterisk and you should be fine.
Also worth mentioning, ASP.NET Core 3.0 uses `UseEndpoints` instead of `UseMvc`, so the correct way to configure your routes will be following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("blog", "{id}-animal", new { controller = "animal", action = "index" });
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```